# How to get Microsoft Windows 10/11 online account name using C++/Qt6?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, qt6

The code, presumably, was working before, and returns empty string now.
Was something about `NetUserGetInfo` changed recently?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <lmaccess.h>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString name;
    TCHAR  infoBuf[32767];
    DWORD  bufCharCount = 32767;
    LPUSER_INFO_0 pBuf = nullptr;

    GetUserName( infoBuf, &bufCharCount ); // infoBuf - local username
    NetUserGetInfo(nullptr,infoBuf,2, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE*>(&pBuf));
    if (pBuf != nullptr)
    {
        LPUSER_INFO_2 pBuf2 = LPUSER_INFO_2(pBuf);
        name = QString::fromWCharArray( pBuf2->usri2_full_name );
    }
    qDebug() << "name: " << name;
    QLabel * label = new QLabel("|" + name + "|");
    label->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: What's the return value from `NetUserGetInfo` ?

Comment: DWORD (aka unsigned long)

Comment: Not the type the value ?  If the call to `NetUserGetInfo` is failing what does it return ?

Comment: `NetUserGetInfo` returns `NERR_Success`

Comment: Combining GetUserName with NetUserGetInfo is not 100% guaranteed. Read the remarks of both API, it very much depends on the current security setup, so it's possible it used to work for some reason and doesn't anymore for some reason. You should at least use GetUserNameEx to ensure a given format

Answer (score 1):

Changes in API behaviors usually happen due to changes in security policies, unless documented otherwise. In that case, your initial assumptions about the API may have been wrong to begin with. As described in [@SimonMourier's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74087201/#comment130811330_74087201) above.

> Combining GetUserName with NetUserGetInfo is not 100% guaranteed. Read the remarks of both API, it very much depends on the current security setup, so it's possible it used to work for some reason and doesn't anymore for some reason. You should at least use GetUserNameEx to ensure a given format

That being said, you are using `NetUserGetInfo()` incorrectly. You are asking for level 2, so it will output a `USER_INFO_2*` pointer, not a `USER_INFO_0*` pointer that needs to be typecasted to `USER_INFO_2*`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <lmaccess.h>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString name;
    WCHAR userName[UNLEN+1];
    DWORD userNameCount = UNLEN+1;
    LPUSER_INFO_2 pBuf = nullptr;

    GetUserNameW( userName, &userNameCount ); // local username
    if (NetUserGetInfo(nullptr, userName, 2, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE*>(&pBuf)) == NERR_Success && pBuf != nullptr)
    {
        name = QString::fromWCharArray( pBuf->usri2_full_name );
        NetApiBufferFree(pBuf);
    }

    qDebug() << "name: " << name;
    QLabel * label = new QLabel("|" + name + "|");
    label->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but results is the same - an empty string. Also, how to output the `userName` from this WCHAR[] format?

Comment: @yalov `WCHAR` is an alias for `wchar_t`. You output it the same way you output any other wide string. `std::wcout`, `MessageBoxW()`, `qDebug()`, they will all work.

Comment: `MessageBoxW()` is way to go. Other approaches or, probably, the terminal where they output have problems, and output first letter, or some hex

Answer (score 1):

[GetUserName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamew) cannot react to **Domain**. [NetUserGetInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusergetinfo) returns **NERR_UserNotFound** when the account is a domain account according to my test. You can use [NetUserEnum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuserenum#examples) to retrieve information about all user accounts on the local computer.
Edit User Full Name in Computer Management:
[image: Computer Management Tool]
[image]

Comment: the `NetUserEnum` loops through 7 accounts (3 are mine, and 4 are system's). I was able to verify `.usri2_name`, using the MessageBoxW, but `.usri2_full_name` is still empty

Comment: [`usri2_full_name` can be a NULL string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/ns-lmaccess-user_info_2#members) if not specified at adding User in **Computer Management** tool or [NetUserAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuseradd).

Comment: I am not sure where to specify the full name in the Computer Management window. I have the full name specified on the microsoft account, connected to the current local account

Comment: @yalov Computer Management->Local Users and Groups->Users->Properties

Comment: I see, "Local Users and Groups" does not exist in the Win10/11 Home, but there is third-party https://github.com/proviq/AccountManagement . After I filled in the full name field in the app, OP code worked as expected. My theory, that if you create new account using Microsoft account, the full name is autofilled, but if you create local account, and then create connection to the microsoft account - the full name field is empty.